# Magento, Plesk and Varnish

Tags: magento, ssl, varnish, plesk

I am running the following setup:

1. Magento 1.9.3.1
2. Varnish 3.0.5-2 - package installed from here https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/turpentine-varnish-cache.html
3. Ubuntu 14.04
4. Plesk 17.0.17

I have installed both varnish on the server and the plugin within magento, saved the configuration properly (from magento admin), however I am missing a configuration setting somewhere since the Varnish headers do not show up.

`/etc/default/varnish` has the following content:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :443 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,8192m\
             -p esi_syntax=0x2\
             -p cli_buffer=16384"
```

I did set it up to listen on 443 because the website has a ssl certificate.

When I try to see who is listening 443 with `netstat -ntlp | grep -w 443` I get the following response:

```
tcp        0      0 91.250.103.173:443      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9171/nginx: worker
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      6109/varnishd
```

So in addition to this I tried to modify the port where nginx listens by setting the listening port to 444 like this `listen 444 ssl;`. It did not work.

When I try to see the headers with `curl` there is no X-Varnish header.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use Varnish 4 and no Plesk. None or mostly none of the control panels out there would be compatible with Varnish.

Comment: @DanielV. Strong claims require evidence. Varnish always requires an exceptional attention, so maybe to drop varnish?

Comment: @DanielV. I see. Thank you

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin, sure you should drop Varnish and concentrate on hosting more and more clients using Plesk for sites that would never see real world traffic :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,8192m\
         -p esi_syntax=0x2\
         -p cli_buffer=16384"
```

you should change port listen to **nginx** or **apache** to 8080
and config default.vcl change port **backend 8080**